# How to make editable cards in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can't figure out how to make card text editable and reflect that changes in the card state.

So, I have an input field where I type in text and click on add button which makes a call for add function,

```
addFunction = () => {
this.cardId ++;
this.setState({
                t_c: [
                    ...this.state.t_c,
                    {
                        cardId: this.cardId,
                        terms: this.state.terms
                    }
                ]
            });
}
```

So terms are the text and its provided with cardId as id.

So to display the data inside state t_c I am mapping each object inside the state and displaying them,

```
{this.state.t_c.map(terms =>
              <section>
                <section>
                     <input defaultValue={terms.terms} />
                </section>
                <img ..../>
              </section>
 )}
```

The problem here if I try to change the added terms the changes are not displayed in the t_c state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, you should approach your problem like it's a [Form](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html).

Form components are whether [controlled](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) or [uncontrolled](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html). For your scenario, if you want to save every change you have done to state, you should implement your input as controlled.

```
<section>
  <input 
    value={terms.terms}
    onChange={(e) => setTerms(/* your state controller code */)}
  />
</section>
```

Also to see the changes, you are missing key prop to populated sections. Change mapping function to this and you'll see the changes.

```
{this.state.t_c.map((terms, t_index)=>
  <section key={"terms" + t_index}>
    <section>
      <input defaultValue={terms.terms} />
    </section>
    <img ..../>
  </section>
 )}
```

See more detail [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html).